# AngularJS - Add array to $cookie

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I'm learning my Angular and attempting to develop a simple shopping cart.

I'd like to add NgCookies into my application to store the item in a cart.

Can someone advise how I add a object to a cookie?

I have the following function on my controller ...

```
 this.addItemToBasket = function(item) {

        //that.basket.push(item);

        $cookies.put("shopping-cart", item,
        {
        });

        alert($cookies.get("shopping-cart"));
    },
```

If you need more information or code, please comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular 1.4 you can do this below.

```
  var obj = {};
  $cookies.putObject('name', obj);
```

If you are in versions below, you could use `JSON.Stringify(obj);`